# how to get specific data key in json response from api twitter in python

Tags: python, json, api, twitter, web-crawler

I am trying to get attributes of only "id" and "text" in the result of response API Twitter. But the below code result all key attribute. How to get the data "id" and "text"?

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        with open('python2.json', 'a') as f:
            f.write(data)
            return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
    return True

def on_error(self, status_code):
    if status_code == 420:
        print(status_code)
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    hasil = stream.filter(track=['wedding','sunday'])
```

the result :

```
 {"created_at":"Sun Apr 04 17:16:28,
 "id":1378758380722946049,
 "id_str":"1378758380722946049",
 "text":"Nonton wedding atta aurel jadi pen nikah",
 "source":"Twitter Web",
 "truncated":false,
 "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
 "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null
 }
```

the expected result just id and text

```
{
 "id":1378758380722946049,
 "text":"Nonton wedding atta aurel jadi pen nikah"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to *only* write a JSON containing the `id` and `text` fields, so this modified version of your code will *correctly* take both those fields out of `jsonData`, create it's own new JSON only containing `id` and `text` (`newJSON`) and then write it to your file.

```
import json
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('python2.json', 'a') as f:
                jsonData = json.loads(data)
                id = jsonData["id"]
                text = jsonData["text"]
                newJSON = {'id': id, 'text': text}
                f.write(json.dumps(data))
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True
```

**P.S.: Your code in your question has severe formatting problems,** `on_data` and `on_error` should be indented under the `StdOutListener` class.